# Search across networked drives that are only sometimes connected

Tags: network, spotlight, search

I've got networked drives at work and networked drives at home. What's a way to set up search so that it automatically applies searches to each drive when connected without having to rebuild the index each time I switch?

I've tried Spotlight, Quicksilver, and Launchbar, and don't see where any of them handle this well. (I use sidekick to change all my other settings, so something that integrates with that could work.)

One thing that would work would be Launchbar or Quicksilver with [Roo Switch](http://rooswitch.com/). But that means maintaining three separate catalogs -- one for home, one for work, and one for everywhere else (i.e. not connected to either set of networked drives). Lame.

Comment: What format is the network mount? Lion server handles this automagically (most of the time)

Comment: At work it's a Windows 2008 server that I connect over to SMB (I get knocked off if I close my laptop lid). At home it's a couple of hard drives connected to an AirPort Extreme.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think Spotlight is the way to go -- Launchbar and Quicksilver seem not to want to have too large of a catalog, which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) is the answer.

Does a search without indexing anything, in real time. Slower than Spotlight, but comforting to us Windows folks, who like to see exactly what the thing's doing. (And in practice it's actually very fast when searching for a filename.)